# Discrete subgroups are lattices

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

If $V$ is an $n$-dimensional real vector space, a *lattice* in $V$ is a subgroup of the form $\Gamma=\mathbb{Z}v_1+\dots+\mathbb{Z}v_m$ where $v_1,\dots,v_m\in V$ are are $\mathbb{R}$-linearly independent. The lattice is *complete* if $m=n$.

Theorem: A subgroup $\Gamma\subset V$ is a lattice iff it is discrete.

This is proven in Neukirch's *Algebraic Number Theory* but there is a step I don't understand. Here's his proof:

[image]

In the last step, why does $q\Gamma\subset \Gamma_0$?

**UPDATE**: Also,  in the line just before that, why does that end the proof that $(\Gamma:\Gamma_0)$ is finite? I see it proves that there are finite $\mu_i$, but why finite $\gamma_i$?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The additive group $\Gamma/\Gamma_0$ has order $q$, so for every $\gamma+\Gamma_0\in\Gamma/\Gamma_0$, $q(\gamma+\Gamma_0)=0+\Gamma_0=\Gamma_0$. But $q(\gamma+\Gamma_0)=q\gamma+\Gamma_0$, so $q\gamma+\Gamma_0=\Gamma_0$, and therefore $q\gamma\in\Gamma_0$. Since $\gamma\in\Gamma$ was arbitrary, $q\Gamma\subseteq\Gamma_0$.

Comment: So this is true in general: if $G$ is a group and $H$ is a subgroup of finite index $q$, then $qH\subset G$. I thought it was something specific to the groups in the proof. Thank you!

Comment: @user46225: You have it backwards: it should be $qG\subseteq H$. That’s true in general for **additive** groups; for a multiplicative group it would be $G^q\subseteq H$.

Comment: Dear Brian, there's another step in the proof which I don't understand. Why is the set $\{\gamma_i\}$ finite? I understand why the $\{\mu_i\}$ are finite, but I don't see why it implies the $\{\gamma_i\}$ are as well.

Comment: @user46225: Because the map $\gamma_i\to\mu_i$ is a bijection. Suppose that $\mu_i=\mu_j$; then $\gamma_i-\gamma_j\in\Gamma_0$, and therefore $i=j$, since the $\gamma_i$’s were all from different cosets of $\Gamma_0$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, Excuse me but let me ask you the following question: In the first paragraph of the proof (uploaded page of the book) author proves that if $\Gamma$ is a discrete subgroup of $V$, then $\Gamma$ is closed. Am I right that his proof actually shows that $\Gamma'=\varnothing$ (where $\Gamma'$ - the set of limit points of $\Gamma$)? Thank you!

Comment: @RFZ: Yes, because if $S$ is any closed, discrete subset of any topological space $X$, then $S'=\varnothing$: every point of $S$ has an open nbhd that contains no other point of $S$, since $S$ is discrete, and $X\setminus S$ is an open nbhd of every point not in $S$, since $S$ is closed, so no point of $X$ is a limit point of $S$.

Comment: I am sorry but I am bit confused with the last sentence "so no point of $X$ is a limit point of $S$". Why? What happens if $x\in S'$ for some $x\in X$? I cannot understand where is the contradiction

Comment: @RFZ: There is no contradiction: I gave a direct proof that $S'=\varnothing$, i.e., that no point of $X$ is a limit point of $S$. I’ll restate it in slightly different words. If $x\in S$, then $x$ has an open nbhd $U$ such that $U\cap S=\{x\}$ (since $S$ is discrete), so $x\notin S'$ (i.e., $x$ is not a limit point of $S$). And if $x\in X\setminus S$, then $X\setminus S$ is an open nbhd of $x$ that is completely disjoint from $S$ (since $S$ is closed), so $x\notin S'$ (i.e., $x$ is not a limit point of $S$).