# Proof that a discrete subgroup of $\mathbb(R)^n$ is isomorphic to an integer lattice

Tags: group-theory

I have to prove that a discrete subgroup or $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a lattice, which I am doing in a manner similar to the one in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247528/discrete-subgroups-are-lattices). However, I am unable to understand the method described there as I haven't seen what indexes and cosets are yet.

---

I am given an outline, where $G$ is a discrete subgroup, $F$ is the vector space generated by $G$ of basis $\{a_1,...,a_p\}$, and $H$ is the subgroup of $G$ generated by $\{a_1,...,a_p\}$.

Let $P = G \cap\{ \sum\limits_{i=1}^{p}\lambda_i a_i, 0 \leq \lambda_i < 1 \} $. I have so far proven that $P$ is finite and that for every $x\in G$, there exists unique $(y,z)\in H \times P$ such that $x=y+z$.

I now have to prove that there exists $k>0$ such that $kx\in H$, therefore, by writing $kx=y_k+z_k$, there exists $z_k=0$. How do I prove this?

---

The rest of the proof is limpid, given that it will prove that $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^p$.

Comment: I guess the answer is included in the question I linked, only I need translated to an easier level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer, through proving that $z_k$ is not injective. As it takes finitely many values, there exists $(k,n)\in {(\mathbb{N}^*)}^2$ such that $z_k = z_{k+n}$. Thus,

$$kx-y_k=(k+n)x-y_{k+n} \iff nx = y_{k+n}-y_k\in H$$

Therefore, there exists an $n\in\mathbb{N}^*$ such that $nx\in H$.