# Proving every discrete subgroup of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^m$ with $m \leq n$

Tags: group-isomorphism

I have proven that every discrete subgroup of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is isomorphic to a $\mathbb{Z}^m$, but with no condition on $m$ (potentially, $m>n$). How do I prove that $m\leq n$?

I have tried doing it through an induction, which seems easiest but I can't really get the induction down (basis is easy).

Comment: You will find a proof in Bourbaki's *General Topology, Chapters 5–10*, chapter 7, § 1.1 and also in Duistermaat and Kolk's *Lie Groups*, § 1.12.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos the proof used by Bourbaki is pretty much the same as the one I did, except I don't understand how he finishes it. Using his notations, we have every $t_i$ rational, but doesn't that mean that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is isomophic to a subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}^n$ rather than Z?

Comment: I can't comment on that, since I don't have Bourbaki's textbook at hand right now and I don't remember how the proof goes.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have $m>n$. You may throw away some generators and
assume that $m=n+1$. In this case you have $n+1$ generators of
your group $v_1,\ldots,v_{n+1}$. They cannot be linearly independent
over $\Bbb R$, but they are linearly independent over $\Bbb Q$.
We can assume for some $r\le n$ that $v_1,\ldots,v_r$
are linearly independent over $\Bbb R$ but that
$$v_{r+1}=a_1 v_1+\cdots +a_r v_r$$
with the $a_i\in\Bbb R$. Without loss we may assume $a_1\notin\Bbb Q$. For each $k\in \Bbb N$,
$$\{ka_1\}v_1+\cdots+\{k a_r\}v_r\in G$$
where $\{x\}$ denotes the integer part of $x$. As all the $\{ka_1\}$
are distinct, these are infinitely many elements of $G$ in a bounded
region, contradicting discreteness.

Comment: This may be because I haven't seen it yet, but I don't understand why $G \simeq \mathbb{Z}^m$ implies that there exists a $m$-sized generator group?
Also, do we suppose without loss $a_1$ not to be a rational?

Comment: The image of $(1,0,...), (0,1,...)$ etc. under the isomorphism

Answer (score 0):

I have also found an answer, more fitting to the method I used for solving the problem. Using the notations from [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2452590/proof-that-a-discrete-subgroup-of-mathbbrn-is-isomorphic-to-an-integer-lat), we have $P$ finite, so if we denote $l=\#(P)$ and $r=lcm(1,...,l)$ we have:

$$\forall x \in G, \exists (n_1,...,n_p) \in \mathbb{Z}^p, rx = n_1 a_1+...+n_p a_p$$

And therefore, $G$ can be injected in $\mathbb{Z}^n$, and is therefore isomorphic to a $\mathbb{Z}^m, m\leq n$ (see previous question and answer).